# Documentation in md, pdf and html format

Tags: github, documentation

I'm working on an opensource project on Github. I'd created some documents in Github's md format. However I want those documents available in three formats:

1. PDF: To be downloaded with project
2. HTML: To be hosted on my personal site.
3. Markdown (.md): For Github.

Obviously I'd not prefer to write them thrice. Is there any way I write it once anywhere (although MS Word preferred) and it could be converted to other two formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

I'd write in Markdown and convert to the others.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is DITA. Its free reference implementation, the DITA Open Toolkit, lets you generate HTML and PDF out of the box, and can be customized to generate Markdown as well.

But, DITA might be a more sophisticated solution than you need, depending on your requirements for content reuse, the size of your docs, how frequently you update, whether you will be employing a technical writer to maintain and update your docs... It's a powerful solution better suited for a dedicated documentation effort than a one time ad-hoc situation.